# efficient python function to get value of specific key in nested dict without an external lib and without knowing concret static path to key in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, nested-loops

### **The following **initial situation**:**

I am looking for a custom function that will extract a corresponding value from a nested dict and return it without external libs and without kowning the whole static path to the corresponding key. The function "search path" (dict key) should be similar to the CSS or XPATH selector, e.g.

`getValue(nestedDict, "[subkey1][subkey42InSubkey1]") # "[subkey1][subkey42InSubkey1]" = "search path"`

This function (`getValue()`) should search within the `nestedDict` for the key `subkey1` and within that for `subkey42InSubkey1` and then return the value if found or None.

However, the function should be so dynamic that the depth of the nested dict doesn't matter.
In addition, the "search path" should be specified relatively, i.e. the absolute path through the whole nested dict doesn't have to be known.

## **Question:**

**Can you please help me to create such a function?**
Should such a function be solved via recursion to be more efficient than loops?

*Thank you very much for your help!*

### Python Code

```py
    test_dict = {
        "a" : "1",
        "b" : {
            "1" : 2,
            "2" : 4711,
            "3" : {
                "b31" : 31
            },
            "4" : 4
        },
        "c" : "3",
        "d" : {
            "1" : 5,
            "2" : 9,
            "3" : {
                "c31" : 55
            }
        }
    }
    test_result = 55

    # get value in nested dict like CSS- respectively XPATH Selector
    def getValue(nestedDict, key):
        #TODO
        result = None
        return result 
    
####################################################################################
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        result = getValue(test_dict, "[3][c31]") # should return 55 as a result
        # the following call should yield the same result!
        result2 = getValue(test_dict, "[d][3][c31]") # should return 55 as a result too
        assert result == test_result
        print(result)
```

I have a "non-clean code" solution that I am unhappy with myself, so I refrain from posting it here so as not to create a bias in answering the question unintentionally. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Your solution will require recursion to allow for unknown dictionary depth. You will also need to define the "rules" for how the search criteria are specified - e.g., is it always going to be in the form of "[X][Y]" or could there be multiple levels of brackets and if so what would that mean for your example?

Comment: Shouldn't the function be called with `getValue(test_dicct, "[d][3][c31]")`? Or is that exactly the problem?

Comment: What if there are multiple matches? Shouldn't this return a list of values?

Comment: @DarkKnight Do I understand your comment correctly, whether the rules for searching the path are always defined with square "list" brackets? Yes, so the idea was that an arbitrarily deep dict can be used as the first parameter and the second "search" parameter should also be dynamic to the extent that the syntax always corresponds to the square brackets, but the number (= the depth) remains variable. Does that answer the question? So another allowed call would also be "[x][y][z][zz]" (minimum depth of the dict must be 4), but this would not be syntactically correct: "[X]y[z]".

Comment: @Matthias your suggested call would also be semantically, as well as syntactically correct, but would require that I know the complete path to the "key". This is exactly my problem.

Comment: @user2390182 Yes, it would make sense to return a list or similar data type with all occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

Recursive generator to find all values for a single key anywhere within a nested dict:

```
def find(nested_dict, key):
    if key in nested_dict:
        yield nested_dict[key]
    for v in nested_dict.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from find(v, key)

find(test_dict, "3")
#   {"b31" : 31}
#   {"c31" : 55}
```

Helper to access a concrete path of keys inside a dict:

```
def access(obj, bits):
    for bit in bits:
        obj = obj[bit]  # this can cause errors: obj not a dict or key missing
    return obj
 
access(test_dict, ["d", "3", "c31"])
# 55
access(test_dict, ["b", "4"])
# 4
```

Final value collection:

```
def get_values(nested_dict, search_path):  # e.g. search_path "[d][3][c31]"
    start, *tail = search_path.strip("[]").split("][")
    # start: "d"
    # tail: ["3", "c31"]
    for d in find(nested_dict, start):  # e.g. all occurrences of "d"
        try:
            yield access(d, tail)  # then access e.g. ["3", "c31"] inside of them
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            pass  # key missing, d or any value down the path not a dict

>>> list(get_values(test_dict, "[d][3][c31]"))
[55]
>>> list(get_values(test_dict, "[3][c31]"))
[55]
>>> list(get_values(test_dict, "[c31]"))
[55]
>>> list(get_values(test_dict, "[2]"))
[4711, 9]
>>> list(get_values(test_dict, "[b][2]"))
[4711]
```

This returns a list because there could be more than 1 match. It can easily be modified to just return the first one by changing `yield` to `return` in the `get_values` function.

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution. I tried to understand it before using your code, but unfortunately I did not get the concept behind the three functions in combination with the generator mechanics ("yield"). Could you please give me a brief explanation of how it works and your idea behind the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I do get the same result: `list(get_values(test_dict, "[d][3][c31]")) -> [55]`
I will write up some explanation later.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations of your submitted solution, I understood everything now and my requirements were solved.

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you add '' to your XPATH-like selector. Which I guess you should since dict key aren't necessary string.

```py
def get_value(nested_dict, key):
    res = None
    try:
        res = eval("nested_dict" + key)
    except KeyError:
        for v in nested_dict.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                res = get_value(v, key)
    return res
```

`get_value(test_dict, "['3']['c31']")` return "55" in your example.
Please note that using `eval` is a bad idea if you don't have full control of what your data will be at the time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the point you made. It helped me see the challenge from a different perspective.